# Ember load variable everytime page is loaded

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data, ember.js-3

I want a variable called "name" in my router or controller , which i will use in my hbs template.  Right now , I'm doing this. But the get() is not loading if i navigate backward and click the link to the current page again. It only loads the first time and if i refresh the page . Due to this, the value of name in my form is not reloading everytime i hit the page.

```
      #controller
      name: computed('model.name', {
        get() {
          return this.get('model.name');
        }
      })



      #.hbs
      {{input type = "text" value=name }}
      <button {{action 'update' model.id }}>Update Post</button> 


        #routefile
      import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
      import EmberObject, { computed } from '@ember/object';
      export default Route.extend({
      model(params) {
       return this.get('store').findRecord('post',params.post_id );
      }
      });
```

Comment: what does your route look like? / where is model coming from?

Comment: Added route to my post. I'm not concerned with the model. All I want is to create a variable and set it to a value everytime i access the page

Comment: what's the value of `model`?

Comment: also, what version of ember / ember-data are you using?

Comment: model has an attribute called name and content. version: ember 3.3

Comment: something fishy I'm seeing is the `input` is using the `name` property via the two-way-bound `value` argument, but the `name` property doesn't have a setter -- that could be messing things up.  you have `name` defined as readOnly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `set` method, as otherwise the computed property that you've declared, will be overridden by the value of the input (via the `{{input}}` helper).

```
  name: computed('model.name', {
    get() {
      return this.get('model.name');
    },
    set(key, value) {
      return value;
    }
  })
```